# How to add a third-party DLL to a DockerFile? C#

Tags: docker, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a multi layered project and a third party DLL file and I want to dockerize them. I added a dockerfile into my webApi project and tried to build it but this error occurred:

> 3>Step 7/22 : COPY ["D:/MultiLayeredProject/output/MultiLayeredProject/PluginProject.dll", "MultiLayeredProject/"]
> 3>COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder959745697/D:/MultiLayeredProject/output/MultiLayeredProject/PluginProject.dll: no such file or directory
> 3>C:\Users~~\source\repos\MultiLayeredProject\MultiLayeredProject\Dockerfile : error CTC1014: Docker command failed with exit code 1.
> 3>C:\Users~~\source\repos\MultiLayeredProject\MultiLayeredProject\Dockerfile : error CTC1014: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder959745697/D:/MultiLayeredProject/output/MultiLayeredProject/PluginProject.dll: no such file or directory

How can I add an external DLL to the dockerfile? My dockerfile is like below:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["D:/MultiLayeredProject/output/MultiLayeredProject/PluginProject.dll", "MultiLayeredProject/"]
COPY ["MultiLayeredProject/MultiLayeredProject.csproj", "MultiLayeredProject/"]
COPY ["AppService/AppService.csproj", "AppService/"]
COPY ["Core/Core.csproj", "Core/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MultiLayeredProject/MultiLayeredProject.csproj"`
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MultiLayeredProject"
RUN dotnet build "MultiLayeredProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MultiLayeredProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MultiLayeredProject.dll"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, your third-part dll is a part of project folder. So, instead of using absolute path to file, try to use relative path, like:

`COPY ["output/MultiLayeredProject/PluginProject.dll", "MultiLayeredProject/"]`

When you call `docker build`, docker cli sends your project structure (context) to docker daemon (inside Linux OS) and there is no `D:/...` path.